While booting Ubuntu screen stuck on splash screen
I was sharing my screen on Discord when I discovered that my VS Code was not opening. I googled the problem and found the command code --verbose
(which tells what's going on with VS Code.)
After running that command, I tried to reboot my system, but it got stuck on the boot screen.
